# How does a DataObjects::SQLError object's .code correspond to the error issued by the database?

Tags: ruby, postgresql, datamapper

So I'm doing some business logic and want to run some code that goes like

`select id from blah where foo = 1234 for update nolock`

This code throws a DataMapper::SQLError when the corresponding row in `blah` is locked. This is desirable behavior; I would like to catch this error and use it to inform my application logic. But I want to re-throw any other SQL errors, because they're different than the case I'm programming for, and catching them in the same way would be wrong.

The error object returned has a string error message, and a numeric code (`50463045`). It seems like comparing on the numeric code would be great, but I don't want to embed the constant `50463045` in my code without some modicum of understanding of how the heck it was determined. Notably, the [Postgres manual suggests that the error code for this state](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.0/static/errcodes-appendix.html) is `55P03`, and that doesn't seem to be the same thing. I don't have any idea how much I can trust this magic number, and how to determine it except for experimentally, so I'm not really comfortable with using it.

How is the error code determined?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Internet was distressingly unhelpful, since searching for stuff about DataObjects SQL errors seems to mostly return problems with other software raising the errors, not information on the errors themselves... but after locating the right source code and browsing around through the source code I finally located [do_postgres.c](https://github.com/datamapper/do/blob/master/do_postgres/ext/do_postgres/do_postgres.c):

```
void do_postgres_raise_error(VALUE self, PGresult *result, VALUE query) {
  const char *message = PQresultErrorMessage(result);
  char *sql_state = PQresultErrorField(result, PG_DIAG_SQLSTATE);
  int postgres_errno = MAKE_SQLSTATE(sql_state[0], sql_state[1], sql_state[2], sql_state[3], sql_state[4]);

  PQclear(result);

  data_objects_raise_error(self, do_postgres_errors, postgres_errno, message, query, rb_str_new2(sql_state));
}
```

Notice how a 5-character state is passed to `MAKE_SQLSTATE`... and then also passed to `data_objects_raise_error` itself. I couldn't track down where MAKE_SQLSTATE is defined to figure out what crazy manipulations are going on to make this integer, but it appears I can just use the error object's `.sqlstate` property directly, and make my condition `e.sqlstate == '55P03'`.